# ASP MVC3 Use image as link to a different View/Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Sorry if this is a benign question but still new to ASP MVC3 - what is the best syntax for using an image as a link? It needs to navigate to the `Index.cshtml` page of another Controller (called `Home`).

What I have below causes the image to completely disappear:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")><img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Monet3.png")" id="MonetSig" /></a>
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this. Check your path if its correct

Comment: benign: showing kindness and gentleness.  Would you rather we only answer malignant questions? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that there is a closing `"` missing after `@Url.Action("Index", "Home")` it might be the problem

Comment: Good catch, thx. Oddly enough, it is now surrounded by a blue box. Any idea why this would happen? Have nothing like this specified in the css, just position info.

Comment: @NealR that is the default for images inside link tags. You can create a CSS rule  `a img { border: none }` and that will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use CSS to give the anchor a background image.  This way you can easily change the image for mobile or tablets:

CSS:

```
#MonetSig {
    display: block;
    width:100px; /* change this to your image width and height */
    height:100px;
    background: url('../images/Monet3.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Html:

```
<a id="MonetSig" href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")"></a>
```